# Where can I find fio.lib and fmath.lib on Fortran x64 installation in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, fortran, 64-bit, intel-fortran

I am in the process of re-writing a code that was written in 32 bit (by someone else that is no-longer around!) to 64 bit. Compiling it requires linking it to a couple of 64 bit Fortran libraries (fio.lib and fmath.lib.)

I installed the Redistributable Fortran library package for Intel 64 but I don't see either of the above libraries in there (under \Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\Intel64.) Can anyone point me where I can find the 64 bit versions of these libraries?

OS: Windows

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Redistributable package contains just .dlls needed for running the executable/library. For development you need .lib files which are under your Intel Fortran 64bit Compiler directory structure. It differs from version to version, try to look in the release notes for your compiler. E.g. for [ifort 11.1 (section 2.4)](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/164251/release-notesf-111-w-en-u8.pdf) it would be

```
C:\Program Files\Intel\Compiler\11.1\lib\intel64\*
```